# Ext js filtering on a already filtered data set

Tags: extjs

I am currently using `getStore.addFilter()` with data store to append filters. But as I add new filters, it disregards my previous filters, because according to the api:

> add filter adds a new Filter to this Store's filter set and by
>   default, applies the updated filter set to the Store's unfiltered
>   dataset.

How can i add a filter and filter on the already filtered data set in the store?

Comment: `addFilter` will **append** to the existing filter set - it doesn't disregard anything.  Are you sure you're not confusing the logic.  ***i.e.*** Combining several separate filters results in the records which match **all** filters - as opposed to the records which match any (boolean **and** not **or**).

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet so we can see what you are doing or even better yet a sencha fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different id for your each filter and store will add or replace depending on filter's id.

`var ageFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
    property: 'age',
    value   : 32,
    id:'agefilter'
});`